# Should these names coincide in WPF application project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, messagebox, mainwindow

I would like to know if this names (StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" and MainWindow.xaml) should coincide. For example, if I'm going to rename *MainWindow.xaml* to e.g. *MsgBox.xaml*.

Please look at pic and code sample.

[Solution explorer tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpbM5.png)

**App.xaml of project CustomMessageBox**

```
<Application x:Class="CustomMessageBox.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomMessageBox"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"> <!-- this name -->
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

Please any comments and thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, they must coincide. StartupUri defines the resource (window) that will be load at application's start up event

Comment: Another way would be to handle what you want to show by overriding Application's OnStartUp method and calling something like  `new MsgBox().Show()` if you go this way then you should get rid of StartupUri markup

Comment: More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startupuri?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I've got that.Thank you.

Comment: Thank you guys. This is my yesterdays buried question on the similar issue. Could someone make some comments? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838171/an-exception-while-calling-wpf-app-from-class-library?noredirect=1#comment92601547_52838171

Answer (score 1):

That is the name of the window that will be opened when the app starts. If you rename the window without changing the StartupURI you will get a `System.IO.IOException`,  `Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'`.

Comment: Thank you guys. This is my yesterdays buried question on the similar issue. Could someone make some comments? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838171/an-exception-while-calling-wpf-app-from-class-library?noredirect=1#comment92601547_52838171